# why do we use ApacheHttpClient instead of HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, http

Why do we use `ApacheHttpClient`  instead of `HttpURLConnection`? And in which cases do we prefer `HttpUrlConnection`? Apache clients are deprecated but still we are using it - why?

Answer (score 2):

read this blog written by Jesse
Wilson from the Dalvik
team.: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

> **ApacheHttpClient**
>
> DefaultHttpClient and its sibling AndroidHttpClient are extensible
>   HTTP clients suitable for web browsers. They have large and flexible
>   APIs. Their implementation is stable and they have few bugs.
>
> **HttpURLConnection**
>
> HttpURLConnection is a general-purpose, lightweight HTTP client
>   suitable for most applications. This class has humble beginnings, but
>   its focused API has made it easy for us to improve steadily.

For more detail are [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Comment: I have already gone through these links,while searching more stuff about it I came to know that HttpURLConncection is better above the version Eclair and Froyo.but at the same time It does't provide full flexibility and fuctionality needed by many app I just wanted to know in which case Apache clients are better ?

Answer (score 0):

A more specific answer would be opinion-based, but google recommends  HttpClient up to Android 2.2, and UrlConnection after that.

See http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html